# How do I properly import a SSL certificate

Tags: linux, ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I am trying to import a SSL certificate on Ubuntu 14.04. I have downloaded an SSL certificate using

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect pypi.python.org:443
```

Afterward, I copied the certificate to `/etc/ssl/certs` (this is where $SSL_CERT_DIR points to and where my working certificates are). However when I re-run the command

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect pypi.python.org:443
```

I still get

```
Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should state the OS or platform you are using. Generally speaking, `openssl s_client -showcerts ... -CAfile <ca-root>`. OpenSSL does not trust anything by default. You have to instruct it to trust something. This is in contrast to web browsers, which trust just about anything, including the wrong CA for a server. You may need to perform a `c_rehash` on `/etc/ssl/certs`. Also see, for example, Ubuntu's [`update-ca-certificates` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html).

Comment: @jww I am running Ubutntu Server 14.04 I tried running update-ca-certificates but no luck. I expect that after  I expect that after putting the certificate  in /etc/ssl/certs I will no longer have to use -CAfile. Am I wrong?

Comment: *"I expect that after I expect that after putting the certificate in /etc/ssl/certs I will no longer have to use `-CAfile`"* - I'm not sure. Debian is fairly screwed up; cf., [Debian | ServicesSSL](https://wiki.debian.org/ServicesSSL). I'm not sure what Ubuntu does (or does not do) downstream. Based on your results from [`update-ca-certificates`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html) it sounds like they do something but it does not work. I've found `-CAfile` works everywhere, so I always use it. Another you may be interested in is `CApath`.

Comment: On checking one of my old (and rather out-of-date) test systems it appears Ubuntu 14.04 OpenSSL is among those affected by https://superuser.com/questions/903247/ssl-root-ca-certificate-is-not-recognized-although-present-in-the-trust-store/

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I am running OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014 so this seems to be the case. Thanks, add this an  answer and I will accept it .

Comment: This was an OpenSSL bug see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/903247/ssl-root-ca-certificate-is-not-recognized-although-present-in-the-trust-store/) question.